# How to split string based on character only if cell in same row in adjacent column is blank

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame that looks like this.

Here is my before view.

```
              string  the_date

-rw-r--r--   12 30067    10224
-rw-r--r--   64 30067    10224
-rw-r--r--   64 30067    10224
```

I am looking for a line of code, or a couple, that will split the dates after the '_' character into the field named 'the_date', but only if 'the_date' is empty.  Something like this, I think:

```
df_all_files = pd.DataFrame(df_all_files.string.str.rsplit('',1).tolist(), columns = ['string','the_date'])
```

Comment: It's more or less clear what you're trying to do, but why don't you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve? This would make it easier to provide you with a solution that actually works in the context you're in, instead of some imagined scenario.

Comment: Well, I thought I did exactly that with my before and after examples.  Again, if a date appears in the field named 'the_date', I want to skip this row, but if this is blank, I want to split a string, based on the last '_' character in the string, and move the date from the field named 'string' to the field named 'the_date'.  How can I do that?

Comment: Your examples were good, thanks for that, your problem description is clear. But the intended way to share the problem is in a single bit of code that runs, with some example data included - it allows people trying to help you to instantly see the issue and work from there. I'll provide an answer below, but I'm not sure if it fits with the rest of your code - see how you go. Note how my answer is complete and runs by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use pandas, and the *df* variable is your dataframe above, you may try the following:

```
df.loc[df['the_date'].isnull(), 'the_date'] = df['string'].apply(lambda x:x.split('_')[-1])
```

Comment: Nice one kerwei!  Thanks for sharing this with me!!

Comment: @ryguy72 Glad that it helped! :)